# Transition effect on CSS pull-out menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pull-out menu on my web page, however the 'reveal' isn't as smooth as it could be.

See my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kcp6hn7e/

Is it possible to use a simple transition effect so the menu reveals when I click the burger icon?

```js
(function()
{
    'use strict';
    var toggleX = document.querySelector('.toggle-x');
    var classActive = 'active';
    var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.className = 'toggle-icon-line';
    toggleX.appendChild(innerDiv);
    toggleX.addEventListener('click', onClickHandler);

    function onClickHandler(evt)
    {
        (this.classList.contains(classActive) === true) ? this.classList.remove(classActive): this.classList.add(classActive);

        $('.menu-wrap').toggleClass('open');
        
    }
    
})();
```

```css
  /************Reset**************/
  *,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
  html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

  html, body, div, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, ol, ul, li, form, fieldset, legend, label, table, header, footer, nav, section { 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
  } 
  ol, ul { 
   list-style: none; 
  }
  header, footer, nav, section, article, hgroup, figure {
   display: block; 
  }
  legend {
   display: none;
  }
  /************End Reset**************/

  /************Global**************/








  /************Custom**************/

  /* Navigation Menu - Background */
  .navigation {
    /* critical sizing and position styles */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow:scroll;
    padding-top:40px;
    
    /* non-critical appearance styles */
    list-style: none;
    background:red;
    text-transform:lowercase;
  }

  /* Navigation Menu - List items */
  .nav-item {
    /* non-critical appearance styles */
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  }

  .nav-item a {
    /* non-critical appearance styles */
    display: block;
    padding-bottom:0;
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .nav-item a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: #666;
  }

  .nav-item a:focus, .nav-item a:active {
   text-decoration:underline;
  }

  /* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */
  .site-wrap {
    /* Critical position and size styles */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: white; /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    
    /* non-critical apperance styles */
    padding: 30px 15px 20px 15px;
  }

  body {
   /* Without this, the body has excess horizontal scroll when the menu is open */
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .content-wrap {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }

  .content {
    position: relative;
    background: #b4bad2;
  }

  .content::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.4s;
    transition: opacity 0.4s, transform 0s 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
  }

  /* Menu */
  .menu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1001;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2.5em 1.5em 0;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(-320px,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.3,1);
  }

  .menu, 
  .icon-list {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .toggle
  {
      z-index: 1002;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 48px;
      height: 48px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      transition: nd 0.3s
  }
  .toggle:focus
  {
      outline: none
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line
  {
      position: absolute;
      top: 23px;
      left: 12px;
      right: 12px;
      height: 2px;
      background: white
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::before, .toggle .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: white;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::before
  {
      top: -9px
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      bottom: -9px
  }
  .toggle-x
  {
      background-color: #00b4ff
  }
  .toggle-x:hover
  {
      background-color: #007eb2
  }
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line
  {
      transition: background 0s linear 0.3s
  }
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::before
  {
      transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: top, transform
  }
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      transition-property: bottom, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: bottom, transform
  }
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::before, .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
      transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s
  }
  .toggle-x.active
  {
      background-color: #007eb2
  }
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line
  {
      background: none
  }
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::before
  {
      top: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg)
  }
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      bottom: 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::before, .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s
  }
  .toggle
  {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 48px;
      height: 48px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      transition: background 0.3s;
  }
  .toggle:focus
  {
      outline: none;
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line
  {
      position: absolute;
      top: (48 / 2) - (48 / 2);
      left: 12px;
      right: 14px;
      height: 2px;
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::before, .toggle .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::before
  {
      top: -( (48 / 2) - (48 / 2) - 14);
  }
  .toggle .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      bottom: -( (48 / 2) - (48 / 2) - 14);
  }
  .toggle-x
  {
      background-color: rgb(0, 180, 255);
  }
  .toggle-x:hover
  {
      background-color: rgb(0, 126, 178);
  }
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line
  {
      transition: background 0s linear 0.3s;
  }
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::before
  {
      transition-property: top, transform;
  }
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      transition-property: bottom, transform;
  }
  .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::before, .toggle-x .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
      transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
  }
  .toggle-x.active
  {
      background-color: rgb(0, 126, 178);
  }
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line
  {
      background: none;
  }
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::before
  {
      top: 0;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      bottom: 0;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::before, .toggle-x.active .toggle-icon-line::after
  {
      transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
  }
  
  .menu-wrap
  {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1001;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 2.5em 1.5em 0;
      font-size: 1.15em;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-320px, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(-320px, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
      transition: transform 0.4s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
  }
  /* Shown menu */

  .menu-wrap
  {
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
      transition: transform 0.8s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
      position: fixed;
  }

  .content::before
  {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s;
      transition: opacity 0.8s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  .open{
      left:750px; 
  }
  .transition{
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
       -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
         -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50â€“12.00 */
            transition: left 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
  }

 .menu-wrap {
  width:750px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-750px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-750px,0,0);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu" class="menu-wrap transition">
  <nav class="menu">
   <ul class="navigation">
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a href="#">Hello There!</a>
    </li>
            </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <div class="toggle toggle-x"></div>

 <div class="site-wrap">

  <div id="container">

   <main id="content" role="main" class="scroll">
    
                <div>
     
              <h1 class="title">welcome</h1>
                    
          </div>

         </main>
            
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the property that the element will transition *from* in a default state; in this case you need to set `left: 0px` on the element in a class that comes before the `open` class, such as `menu-wrap`. See [an update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcp6hn7e/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Use this jsfiddle to help with the animation.
You can use the code from there. 
    [Here --> jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/71/)

```
$('#btn').click(function(e){    
$('#fancy, #btn').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeIn('slow');
});
});

$('#btn-bk').click(function(e){    
$('#bank, #btn-bk').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#fancy, #btn').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like slideToggle myself - and it's in jQuery without jQuery-UI. First, I had to remove your leftward translations and hide the element with `display:none`:

```
.menu-wrap {
    display:none;
    width:750px;
}
```

Also, just FYI, you have .menu-wrap in there twice - would be best to consolidate the two spots in your CSS into one call, so you know what's being applied and where in your code.

Here's a Fiddle using `slideToggle` - http://jsfiddle.net/jrjb6x2a/1/